# Paypal Button - Add action before popup window opens

Tags: javascript, paypal, alert, sandbox, disable

I'm adding the Paypal button to my site. However, I want to do something where the user needs to have filled out certain information (an address box) prior to the button functioning. If the user has filled out the information, when the Paypal button is clicked, it prompts the user to sign in to Paypal (the normal flow). Otherwise, the user receives an `alert`: `alert('Please choose a delivery address');`

I've been trying to do something like the following:

```
$('.paypal-button').on( "click", function() {
  alert('Please choose a delivery address');
});
```

and even tried to disable the button (although this is less optimal), but have discovered that it is not going to work based on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707024/how-to-disable-enable-paypal-button-on-checkbox-activation):

```
$('.paypal-button').prop("disabled",true);
```

Here is the Paypal Sandbox code (you need a real sandbox credential):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

            // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
            // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
            client: {
                sandbox:    'ABCDEcFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqatestlewfBP4-33iV8e1GWU6liB2XYZ',
                production: '<insert production client id>'
            },

            // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
            commit: true,

            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },

            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }

        }, '#paypal-button-container');

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [new docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/validation/#) provide `onInit` and `onClick` options, however as discussed [here](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/139) you cannot trigger the popup by script as it would be blocked. Therefore the async method is buggy as it briefly shows the popup on validation fail.
I implemented the synchronous validation this way:

```
onInit: function(data, actions) {
  // Disable the buttons
  actions.disable();
  // Listen for changes
  $("input[aria-required=true]").change(function() {
      var valid=true;
      $("input[aria-required=true]").each(function(){
          if($(this).val()=="") valid=false;
      });
      if (valid==true) {
        actions.enable();
      } else {
        actions.disable();
      }

  });       
}
```

I was trying to use a validation (wp cf7's built-in) through a listener but there seems to be no way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `validate:` and `onClick:` properties of the PayPal button. There's an [example on the demo site](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/validation) of how this can work.

Comment: seems there used to be something about validation on the link but isn't any more

Comment: there is no validate part in the link